# combobox.FindStringExact can't find string

Tags: winforms, vb.net-2010

I really tried to figure it out why the method FindStringExact cant find the string in the list.

Here's my code:

```
If comboBox.FindStringExact(ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(1).ToString) > 0 Then
   comboBox.SelectedIndex = comboBox.FindStringExact(ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(1).ToString)
End If
```

The string that's having the problem with is "000-characters" and "000-characters & characters", I have checked for extra spaces, the values in my tables are also correct. I was thinking that it has to do with the zeroes to the left and the ampersand in between.

All help would be appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Findstringexact will return index number if searched value was found ..

```
Dim n as Integer = comboBox.FindStringExact(ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(1).ToString)

If n > -1 Then
   comboBox.SelectedIndex = n
End If
```

This formula is for datagrid which numeric cell

Comment: looking at your example made me realize that the index value starts at 0, and the values I was searching for have index 0 in the combobox. I just changed the value to -1 as suggested. Thank you..